# Reading a filename and applying part of that name to a variable

Tags: python

I am looking to filter files in a directory and then assign part of that `filename` (the value I am trying to match changes) to a variable. The structure of the `filename` is consistent with the following example.
`*test file on part-of-filename-of-interest.csv`. The last part of the `filename` is the part I would like to add to a variable value. So it will always be the last part of the filename and after the word `on`.

I am able to filter all the files of interest using the below but I am not sure on how to grab the `part-of-filename-of-interest` section to place it to a variable value.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('dirpath'):
    filters = '*test file on*.csv'
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filters):
        print filename    #I get all the files im interested in but I dont know how to capture the relevant part of the filename to place it in a variable
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a nested loop? [The example in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) doesn't do that.

Comment: Thats because the example doesnt have multiple dirs to go through ;). Regardless of the nested loop, the problem is capturing a partial filename to a variable. Not how to loop files.

Comment: I was able to comprise a working filter based on digitaLink's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using regex expressions to match the part you want.

```
import re
p = re.compile("(?<=on ).+")
filename = "*test file on part-of-filename-of-interest.csv"
new_filename = p.search(filename).group(0)
```

If you don't want the .csv included change the regex expression to this:

```
p = re.compile("(?<=on ).+(?=.csv)")
```

This is a good example of lookahead and lookbehind.

Comment: that almost works, however it prints the `on` word as well.

Comment: This works great `p.search(filename).group(0).replace('on ', '')`

Comment: For the sake of completeness can you please add the above comment code to your answer and ill accept

Comment: Awesome thanks @digitaLink, it also has the filename attach but Im sure I can workout how to clean that up.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the consistency of your pattern, would this work for you?

```
>>> fn = 'test file on part-of-filename-of-interest.csv'
>>> import os
>>> os.path.splitext(fn[fn.find('test file on') + 13:])[0]
'part-of-filename-of-interest'
```

Comment: unfortunately the length of the part of interest does vary

Comment: Thanks for the response BlivetWidget.

Comment: @iNoob How is that unfortunate?  The above function doesn't care how long the part of interest is.

Comment: @BilvetWidget apologies, i miss understood the code.

Comment: @iNoob no worries, it's a bit convoluted.  It would be longer, but clearer perhaps, to make "fn.find('test file on') + 13" its own variable first.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no way to access what you're looking for with `fnmatch`, the simplest and fastest solution is probably a string method:

```
print filename.partition('on')[2]
```